# Nativescript Angular BottomNavigation selectedIndex binding not working

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

My BottomNavigation with selectedIndex binding is not working when loaded, content is not being displayed but the navigation bar is there. If i insert the index normally then it would work. Could anyone advice me on this? Thanks

HTML :

```
<BottomNavigation [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">  <-- Not Working this way
<BottomNavigation selectedIndex="1"> <-- Works fine
```

TS :

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

tabIndex: number = 2;
```

Here is the [Playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=JOb7pi&v=20)

Comment: It is a known bug (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2146). There is  also a workaround there.

Comment: Thanks @Yong ! It's working now with the workaround.